The term "insertion point" in whatwg spec
The quote:

The insertion point is relative to the position of the character immediately after it, it is not an absolute offset into the input stream.

What does it mean? Why not an absolute offset?

In the context:
Insertion point is used for the insertion data from document.write API.
So spec has has following quotes:

Let the old insertion point have the same value as the current insertion point. Let the insertion point be just before the next input character.

If it meets in the first time, the insertion point will be undefined.

Let the insertion point have the value of the old insertion point. (In other words, restore the insertion point to its previous value. This value might be the "undefined" value.)

That step goes after prepare the script element that might be cause of calling document.write
So if the input stream with the time discarding the first characters, it's not clear what the conception of insertion point for if it is always start of stream.
Any thoughts?

I think this allows the input processor to discard previous input after it has been parsed into DOM elements. So it can't count from the beginning.

@Barmar could you expose your thought in detail with some examples if it possible? And it's strange, insertion point will be always 0, this is nonsense, they might as well write insert a string at the beginning of the input stream if, as you say, they discard consumed characters.

Maybe I'm not understanding, but it's not a number, it's a cursor that keeps track of a place in the input stream.

When you call document.write(), it inserts what you write into the input stream at the current point.

@Barmar maybe I don’t understand something either, but if this is a cursor and not a number, how is the position determined?

@Barmar I made an addition to the question

I’ve read this and your previous question, and with all possible respect can I ask why you care? I’m honestly very curious. When I read this, I take it at face value that the insert point can move because document.write can add stuff before it, so tracking an absolute would require a global counter/position, and it just makes sense for implementations to use a relative cursor. And reading some of the spec and history, re-entrant scripts appear to be part of this. But maybe I’m missing something?

@ChrisHaas I study the specifications from time to time in order to better and better understand how the mechanisms work inside.
Regarding the current issue, there are things that are not entirely clear. For example, when consuming a symbol, is it discarded from the stream input or not? The specification doesn't say anything, it just mentions what characters are consumed and what they are not. But essentially the logic is not entirely clear, for me it doesn’t matter what type of offset is here, in any case it will be the current position + the length of the inserted string

As to “consume”, at least, there is further talk that some insertion modes have a state that can “reconsume” the current character and therefore have a temporary buffer. Also, some states, such as "13.2.5.14 RAWTEXT end tag name state" and "13.2.5.17 Script data end tag name ASCII upper alpha" emit extra characters which means to me that it wouldn’t match the original length of the input string anymore.

@ChrisHaas the fact that a character can be reconsumed only indicates that it is being reused, it is not a backward shift along the input stream. The temporary buffer is not the same as the input stream two different things. When the specification says "emit", it doesn't mean that the input stream is being populated with characters, it means that a token has been issued that should be immediately processed through the tree construction stage. The specification explicitly says what affects to the input stream

So I guess I don't understand what your question is? The spec says to "consume" something, and sometimes "reconsume" it (by using the temp buffer). Beyond that, the spec is silent. My general understanding of "consume" as it relates to tech specs is destructive/forgetful, but I don't think the spec cares, that's an implementation detail. Can you come up with a reason that it matters? (Not trying to argue, either. I'm a spec-reader, too. Just really trying to understand why it matters.)

@ChrisHaas My question is exactly why the specifiers specify a relative offset instead of an absolute one. I investigated many sections and came to the conclusion that when characters are added to the input stream, this is always the beginning of the input stream (in case if characters are discarded after use (consuming), but the specification does not say about discarding).

@ChrisHaas But if they are not discarded, then the input stream is replenished with characters through document.write and then the insertion point makes sense, since it works with an extensible input data stream, and the relative offset, as I think, is an offset by the number of inserted characters.

@ChrisHaas I'm trying to understand the intent of the specification. And if such questions arise regarding the interpretation of what is written, does it not mean that the specification should be written more clearly? Since a discrepancy in meanings can lead to different implementations and inconsistencies. My question is just about the right understanding. And the fact that no one has given me an answer to the question with firm confidence just says that.

I just deleted my comment, as I found your issue on GH. That is probably the best place to get an answer. Good luck, I’ll follow this over there!

@MaximPro - Apologies, having re-read my answer, I think it's completely wrong, so I've deleted it. I'll review it later and reinstate it if I can fix it.

@Alohci the intrigue has increased, now I wonder what the corrected answer will be.

@Alohci I don't see what's wrong with your answer. The OP is clearly confused about the insertion point: "I do not see the sense of the insertion point as indicating the position where characters should be inserted into the input stream, since this is always the beginning of the stream. If we always work from the beginning of the input stream, then why do we need an insertion point?" and your answer did explain the edge case they didn't think of

"there are things that are not entirely clear: when consuming a symbol, is it discarded from the stream input or not? The specification doesn't say anything" - the html spec doesn't need to explain anything here, this is standard terminology for streams. "Consume" means "get the current element and move to the next one" (so that when consuming again, it'll return that next one). It's not clear what you mean by "discard" or how you think a stream is implemented. Typically there's a read pointer into some buffer, occasionally some sort of linked list

…and consumed elements are simply ignored as they are no longer needed. Whether they are garbage-collected automatically, dropped explicitly when the stream processing completes, dropped explicitly during stream processing, or not dropped at all (leaking memory?). Or maybe they actually are needed for something else than parsing, like view-source or because some dom strings still point to the buffer. Ultimately doesn't really make a difference, does it? Memory usage is generally left to the implementation.
